# Reflect changes in UIView layer's properties in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

I know we can change UIView layer's properties in IB with keyPath, but can we make the changes be reflected in IB?

For example, I change the cornerRadius of the following UIImageView. I can see the changes in after building the project, but not in the IB itself.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IBDesignable** and **IBInspectable** are what you're looking for. 
From [Appple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/Chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html) and here's something from [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/)

Comment: I guess we really do need to subclass UIView to achieve this. Thanks!